# Unicode keycap not displaying correctly

Tags: html, unicode

To "quickly" display a boxed number (in HTML), I can use the character U+20E3 to achieve this effect:

```
3⃣1  (0033 20E3 0031)
```

[image]

This should [work](http://www.w3.org/2001/06/utf-8-test/combining-keycap.html) with full-width characters. However when I try the following:

```
字⃣  (5B57 20E3)
```

[image]

The character is shifted to the left. This example can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/rkdfLz0p/).

Why is this happening? Is this platform-dependent? Or did I misunderstand the purpose of this character?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The usefulness of combining enclosing keycap characters is substantially limited by several factors. These are not limited to use in HTML. In fact, HTML as such is irrelevant here, though when using these characters in an HTML document, you will see the effects of character rendering in a browser (as opposite to rendering in a text editor, in a word processor, or other software).

First, a combining enclosing keycap character is defined to enclose a *single* character, so the attempt at using one for a digit sequence like “31” could work with some trickery at most. The Unicode FAQ section [Characters and Combining Marks](http://www.unicode.org/faq/char_combmark.html) says:

> Q: Is it possible to apply a diacritic or combining enclosing mark to
>   a sequence of more than one (non-combining) character?
>
> A: No, with the exception of the “double diacritics” deliberately
>   designed to be applied onto a two letter sequence, e.g. U+035D
>   COMBINING DOUBLE BREVE. Neither ZWJ (U+200D ZERO WITDH JOINER) nor CGJ
>   (U+034F COMBINING GRAPHEME JOINER) “glue” characters together in a way
>   that the scope of any following combining character would be affected.
>   To get a character sequence like “Esc” into something like the U+20E3
>   COMBINING ENCLOSING KEYCAP, you must resort to higher-level protocols

Second, to make such a character work, you need a font that contains it. According to my studies, the following fonts contain: U+20E3 COMBINING ENCLOSING KEYCAP: Asana Math, Code2000, FreeMono, FreeSerif, Segoe UI Symbol, Sun-ExtA, Symbola, and unifont. A rather short list, and mostly fonts that users need to download and install on their own. You might find the Free (GNU FreeFont) fonts in Unix and Linux systems and Segoe UI Symbol in modern Windows systems as pre-installed,

Even if a font contains the character, the rendering may be unacceptable. This may depend on rendering software (browser or other), but also on the font. The enclosed character may be badly misplaced. Moreover, the combined character tends to be shifted left, possibly overprinting the preceding character. Although you can usually deal with this with some padding, its amount would be font-dependent.

The following code illustrates the problems, to the extent that the reader’s system has the fonts used:

```html
<p style="font-family: Asana Math">
Press the 3⃣ key or the 字⃣  key.
<p style="font-family: Code2000">
Press the 3⃣ key or the 字⃣  key.
<p style="font-family: FreeMono">
Press the 3⃣ key or the 字⃣  key.
<p style="font-family: FreeSerif">
Press the 3⃣ key or the 字⃣  key.
<p style="font-family: Segoe UI Symbol">
Press the 3⃣ key or the 字⃣  key.
<p style="font-family: Sun-ExtA">
Press the 3⃣ key or the 字⃣  key.
<p style="font-family: Symbola">
Press the 3⃣ key or the 字⃣  key.
<p style="font-family: unifont">
Press the 3⃣ key or the 字⃣  key.
```

The example illustrates an additional problem: the character “字” U+5B57 CJK UNIFIED IDEOGRAPH-5B57 (zì) is not included in all the fonts used. Most seriously, it is not included in FreeSerif and Segoe UI Symbol, which have reasonably good implementations of the enclosing mark. Combining a base character from one font and a diacritic mark from another font is always a tricky game.

Moreover, even when a font contains both characters, the result can be bad. For example, in Code2000, “字” just does not fit inside the keycap glyph.

The conclusion is that in HTML, other methods of producing keycap symbols are much better. Even the relatively simple technique used at SO to render `kbd` markup produces better results and much more reliably and lets you put several characters inside a keycap: <kbd>31</kbd>, <kbd>字</kbd>. And you can modify the technique to create keycaps of your liking.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's more like a font issue, the example you give displayed like this
[image]

on my mac os with chrome. And I don't think appending unicode characters **after** the enclosing keycap character should work effectively

Comment: Interesting. I'm on Windows and the unicode character isn't rendering correctly.